# what is the difference between provider and factory in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

What is difference between provider and factory? I know the difference between factory and service. But could you tell me in simple language what is difference between in provider and factory?
I make a demo in which I use both but work fine but what is difference mean when I use provider and when I use factory ?
 here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqWRNw

```
var app =angular.module('ionicApp',['ionic']);
app.factory('fac',function(){
  var name;
  return {
    getname :function(){
      return  this.name;
    },
    setName:function(name){
      console.log(name)
      this.name=name;
         console.log( this.name)
    }
  }
});
app.controller('cntr',function($scope,fac,pro){
  fac.setName('test');
  console.log(fac.getname()+"--");
  console.log("pro============")
  pro.setName('protest');
  console.log(pro.getname()+"--");
})

app.provider('pro',function(){
  var name;
  return {
    $get :function(){
      return {
        getname:function(){
           return  this.name; 
        },
        setName:function(name){
             this.name=name; 
        }
      }
    }
    }

});
```

Comment: but there it is not written where we use provide and where we use factory

Comment: "... the Provider recipe is the core recipe type and all the other recipe types are just syntactic sugar on top of it. It is the most verbose recipe with the most abilities, but for most services it's overkill." Use it when you need to.